# Carbon DateTime package

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Trying to format a timestamp with Carbon diffForHumans(), passing in the following params, so it reads as:

```
$new_format = $old_format->diffForHumans(['parts' => 1, 'options' => Carbon::CEIL]);
```

When it attempts to format a date ~1 month ago, it leads to an "undefined offset -1" error.

```
echo Carbon::parse('2022-01-11 15:36:29')->diffForHumans(['parts' => 1, 'options' => Carbon::CEIL]);
echo Carbon::parse('2022-01-10 16:57:38')->diffForHumans(['parts' => 1, 'options' => Carbon::CEIL]);
```

The  examples above, the top run works, where as the bottom one errors. Is there an explanation, why it breaks with these params, or better yet a solution that would give me the same result? Changing to Carbon::FLOOR or ROUND works fine, but aren't viable for what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I can confirm this is a bug in Carbon library. I will fix it for next version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is fixed in version 2.57.0. Thanks for the report.

https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/pull/2547

You can test it using `composer update nesbot/carbon`